# How to fix java.lang.noclassdeffounderror javax/xml/bind/jaxbexception on ODI12c List Software - Oracle DB19c - ODI 12c - JDK 11.0.11

Tags: java, oracle19c, oracle-data-integrator

List Software

- Oracle DB19c
- ODI 12c
- JDK 11.0.11

So I got an error

> `java.lang.noclassdeffounderror javax/xml/bind/jaxbexception`

when I have run mapping data on ODI12c So How to fixed it Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

The jaxb APIs are a part of Java EE APIs. The API is completely removed from the Java 11 SDK. With the introduction of modules since Java 9, the java.se module is available on the default classpath, and it doesn’t include Java EE APIs.

To fix the same, you can pass --add-modules java.xml.bind as a command line argument. A better fix is to add the jaxb API as a Maven/Gradle dependancy.

```
<!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>{version}</version>
</dependency>
```

`compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '{version}'`